# OpenGl ES, android FPS

Tags: java, opengl-es, frame-rate

I have created a little program that runs openGL ES 1.1; I also used Log to print my fps.
There is something strange though, when i check the log the fps counter says that each frame i got more than 2000 fps. How is that even possible? If i am not mistake vsync automatically cap your upper frame limit to 60. Thanks in advance.

```
public class FPSCounter {
long startTime = System.nanoTime();
int frames = 0;

public void logFrame() {
    frames++;
    if(System.nanoTime() - startTime >= 1000000000) {
        Log.d("FPSCounter", "fps: " + frames);
        startTime = System.nanoTime();
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Is this the real code? What you log here is just a count of the frames. You never divide by the time to get a frame rate.

Comment: i increment the frame var and then check if 1 second has passed, if its true then i reset the time. Now i see i dont reset the frame var :/

Answer (score 0):

Reset your counter frames.

```
 if(System.nanoTime() - startTime >= 1000000000) {
        Log.d("FPSCounter", "fps: " + frames);
        startTime = System.nanoTime();
        **frames = 0;**
}
```